# Let $V$ be a vector space. Determine all linear transformations $T:V \rightarrow V$ such that $T=T^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space. Determine all linear transformations $T:V \rightarrow V$ such that $T=T^2$. I am given

> $x=T(x)+(x-T(x))$ for every x in V, and show that $V={y:T(y)=y} \oplus N(T)$ as a hint

I don't have a first thought on this problem, what can identity mapping tell us? And what's the general intuition for this problem?

Comment: As a "first thought":  What happens when $V$ is one dimensional?  If $V$ is one dimensional, what is the dimensionality of $N(T)$ forced to be?

Comment: then N(T) is 0?

Comment: Okay.  Now, $V$ is two dimensional.... then three...  When you don't see the pattern; do small examples until you do see it.

Comment: Here is perhaps not an answer but an observation:

$T^2=T$ if and only if there are subspaces $X,Y$ of $V$ such that $V=X\oplus Y$ and $T(x+y)=x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $T^{2}x=Tx$ shows that $Ty=y$ whenever $y=Tx$ for some $x$. So $T$ is the identity map on the range of $T$. It is zero on the kernel of $T$. The hint shows that any vector can be written as  a sum of two vectors, one in the range of $T$ and the other in the kernel of $T$: $x=Tx+(x-Tx)$ and $T(x-Tx)=Tx-T^{2}=Tx-Tx=0$. This all such transformations are determined by the range $T(V)$.