# Prove that $T=T^2$ if and only if $T$ is a projection on $W_1=\{y\in V:T(y)=y\}$ along $N(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space and $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation. Prove that $T=T^2$ if and only if $T$ is a projection on $W_1=\{y\in V:T(y)=y\}$ along $N(T)$.

Does $W_1=\{y\in V:T(y)=y\}$ imply it is an identity map, and how am I supposed to prove that the only way the projection works is letting $0_v\in N(T)$? What's the sketch?

Comment: The $W_1 +$ should be outside the curly brackets.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to edit your question so that it would actually make sense. $W_1$ is the name of a subspace defined by a certain condition. Having "$W_1=y$" inside the curly braces, as in your original post, didn't make sense.

Comment: And what is $N(T)$? Is $V$ assumed to be finite dimensional?

Comment: Here $N(T)$ stands for for the null-space, or the kernel, of the linear transformation $T$.

Comment: T(y)=y could also be a fixed point.

Comment: What is your definition of projection? If I recall correctly, I was told a projection is a transformation satisfying $T^2 =T$ so this exercise is somewhat tautological to me. @zipirovich thanks. I now recall seeing this notation in functional analysis. I much prefer the word *kernel* and never used *nullity space*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $V$ be a vector space. Determine all linear transformations $T:V \rightarrow V$ such that $T=T^2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537554/let-v-be-a-vector-space-determine-all-linear-transformations-tv-rightarrow)  That's twice in less than two hours.